# All job data lost when running Jenkins in Docker and when Jenkins container is stopped

Tags: docker, jenkins

On a VPS server I use the following command to run Jenkins:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

But sometimes, my config error will stop the container, then all my jobs configured in Jenkins are lost.

I follow [this video](https://www.docker.com/use-cases/cicd) to run Jenkins in Docker. 
Is this the right way to run Jenkin in Docker? How to save my jobs in my pulled Jenkins image?

Comment: When you start the stopped container do you use docker start <existing_container_id> or do the docker run again?

Answer (score 3):

You have to attach a volume to the container that point to jenkins home directory. Usually I use:

`docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v /my-absolute-path/where-is-jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`